# Docusaurus v2- Search Bar does not appear while using Build

Tags: algolia, docusaurus

I have created a new site using Docusaurus v2. I had installed the core as well as the theme-search-algolia packages as provided [here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/search).

When I run the site locally using `npm run start`, the Search bar is visible on the top as shown below.

[Locally Started Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihx3w.png)

However, when I use `npm run build` and then `npm run serve`, the Search bar is not visible.

[Build and Serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4N8i.png)

Would be great if you all can help me out with the problem here.

Comment: It is not that easy… You have to setup the Algolia API, request a KEY from then, etc. Read carefully your first link. Also, the Algolia API need to approve you request and you need a proper public IP ou DNS linked to your documentation website.

Comment: [The easy way](https://docsearch.algolia.com/docs/apply), the [do it yourself way](https://docsearch.algolia.com/docs/run-your-own)

Answer (score 0):

It's because previous builds were cached,  preventing newly created themes.

Please update the document that if someone has already done `npm run start` or `npm run build`, then after installing and swizzling, he / she needs to run `yarn docusaurus clear` .

Refer to this link : [Search Bar not shown in top nav](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/4975)